# htaccess reformat get request?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using code igniter,

We are using a dps system that pings us at `example.com/transact/pass?request={base64 encoded string}`

However as is obvious, with code igniter you cannot use get requests.

So I am wondering if it is possible to in .htaccess when the url is hit reformat is so it hits  code igniter as `example.com/transact/pass/{base64 encoded string}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^transact/pass/(.*)$ /transact/pass?request=$1 [L,PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteRule ^transact/pass?request=(.*)$ /transact/pass/$1
```

should extract the request parameter and place it in the last segment.